# Imported component from local vite+vue library not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm researching options for a new project at work. We're thinking of using nuxt (or just regular vue 3) and creating a library where we will be keeping our shared components.

I'm trying to do the initial setup, but am having problems. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QV9wVc8c7g) to create the library and added typescript to it. I created a sample component with a counter and exported it.

The problem is that when I import the component from my library in a consuming project (whether it's the nuxt project or a vanilla vite vue project), the component looks like it's not reactive. Its internal counter is supposed to increase when it's clicked, but it's not updating. There are no errors or warning in the console.

Another issue is that its CSS is not being applied. It has some basic styling defined in the component, but it's not visible. I've created a minimal reproduction repo with setup instructions here: https://github.com/drekembe/vite-reproduction-2342

I've tried searching for similar issues or debugging it myself, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem today with my package and finally, I found the real culprit is the `node_module` inside the package that we tested locally. If you install the local package by `npm link` or install directly with the folder path like `"components": "../components"`, your `node_module` will look like:

```
node_modules
  |
   --components
      |
       --node_modules <-- the culprit here
```

Your package will be shipped with its own `node_module` and inside that module has a `vue` package that is independent of the vue package that you are using in your app. So your components would not work as expected.

To test it, just delete the `node_modules/components/node_modules` and the vite cache `node_modules/.vite` then run `yarn dev` again. You will see your component works fine now.

#### Solution:

- In your package folder `components` run `npm pack` to pack your package. It will [create a tarball for your package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pack). The output is the `components-0.0.0.tgz` file inside the `components` folder. This is the most important part because `npm pack` will create a pack of your package that is similar to what you will publish to the npm registry.
- Now in your test project `my-vite-app` add your package to the `package.json`: `"components": "file:../components/components-0.0.0.tgz"`
- Run `yarn` to install the package and `yarn dev` to run the app and see if your components work.
- Every time you make a change on your package, don't forget to pack the package again and re-install it. You might want to increase your package version to invalidate the yarn cache

Comment: Wouldn't this be really slow during development if you had to `npm pack` every single time a change occurs in your package just so you would see changes in the test project (the project which consumes your package)?

Is there a way where we can re-pack on every change so everything is in sync without switching to terminal every now and then?

Or even better, perhaps there is a better way overall that this problem can be solved?

Comment: @krcky You should only use `npm pack` when you have done development and want to do the final test before publishing the package. For the development process, you can just directly import your component into a Vue project to test it

Comment: So let's go over this again, if you don't mind. First step is `npm link`, so you can test in a project as you develop the package. The problem is, library's components are not reactive due to them having their own node_modules. I just tested that, and that's valid. So if I want to view changes of my library as I develop, in a separate project which consumes my package, what is the workflow, just so I get clear?

Comment: @krcky Let's take a look at [my package](https://github.com/duannx/vue-router-transition/blob/main/dev/src/main.ts). I can do `import VueRouterTransition from '../../src/index'` instead of import from the node_modules. It is the way we test the Vue component. We just use it directly in the test project. No need `npm link` at all

Answer (score 0):

In your `components` folder run :

```
yarn build
```

then run :

```
yarn link
```

in `my-vite-app` folder run :

```
 yarn link "components"
```

in the `maint.ts` import the style :

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'components/dist/style.css'
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately, linking the packages doesn't fix the issue. I was going to link them later on when developing, but first I wanted to test whether a normal install works.
Importing the CSS in main.ts also doesn't solve the styling issue, which is weird. The network inspector shows that the CSS is loaded, but the data-v-* attributes aren't applied to the DOM elements of the component.

Comment: Update: I tried to set up a local npm package repo, pushed the package there and then installed it from the package repo. Everything worked as intended that way. However, when I then try to link the two projects so that I can develop the components in the context of their parent project, they again show no CSS and are not reactive.